# When janusgraph Mixed index is indexed?

Tags: janusgraph

I use Janusgraph 0.2.0 and ES backend.

**when indexed?**

Once a vertex or edge is added and the transaction is successfully committed,  can I consider that the mixed indexes related to the transaction are immediately available?

Or, the mixed indexes are lazily sent to backend by janusgraph after the commit (that is, eventually consistent)?

**when mixed index is down**

If mixed indexes are lazily sent to backend by janusgraph, when the mixed index backend is down, can I successfully commit a transaction which requires mixed indexes?

**index status**

If mixed indexes are lazily sent to backend indexed by, how to check the indexing state (index lag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JanusGraph commit index backend's mutations at the time of transaction commit**

There is a configuration in JanusGraph

**storage.write-time :** default value 100000 ms

> Maximum time (in ms) to wait for a backend write operation to complete successfully. If a backend write operationfails temporarily, JanusGraph will backoff exponentially and retry the operation until the wait time has been exhausted.

The class `IndexTransaction` Wraps the transaction handle of an index and buffers all mutations against an index for efficiency. It will retry until the `storage.write-time` exceeded. After exceeding throws BackendException

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to check index lag? After bulk loading, I want to wait until index backend is synced.

Comment: @takaomag Sorry, at first i was wrong about the index commit. Now updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can go ahead.